# How to Remove keyname from json string

Tags: java, json, string

I have a json string like this.

```
[
            {
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Jam Brong",
                    "image": "https://asdf.asdf.com/asdf/image/upload/w_30,h_30,c_fill/product/fb7d3dcb505fba76262c0c6383d844ae.jpg",
                    "price": "2500",
                    "slug": "133-jam-brong",
                    "short_name": "Jam Brong"
                }
            },
            {
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Jam abcfdfjn",
                    "image": "https://asdf.asdf.com/asdf/image/upload/w_30,h_30,c_fill/product/7bbd3d081dd03c442e4cb27321a7b50c.jpg",
                    "price": "10888",
                    "slug": "87-jam-abcfdfjn",
                    "short_name": "Jam abcfdfjn"
                }
            }
]
```

I need to remove `"_source":{`

so i can get a json string like this.

```
[
            {

                    "name": "Jam Brong",
                    "image": "https://asdf.asdf.com/asdf/image/upload/w_30,h_30,c_fill/product/fb7d3dcb505fba76262c0c6383d844ae.jpg",
                    "price": "2500",
                    "slug": "133-jam-brong",
                    "short_name": "Jam Brong"

            },
            {

                    "name": "Jam abcfdfjn",
                    "image": "https://asdf.asdf.com/asdf/image/upload/w_30,h_30,c_fill/product/7bbd3d081dd03c442e4cb27321a7b50c.jpg",
                    "price": "10888",
                    "slug": "87-jam-abcfdfjn",
                    "short_name": "Jam abcfdfjn"

            }
]
```

I tried to use `replaceAll("("_source:{"),"");`
This code will show me some error like `number expected`.

I don't know how to use `regex` for the string which contains `_` and `{` .

Before i think to use `replaceAll`, i tried `jackson` like this.

```
String responses ="";
        ObjectNode node = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response.toString(), ObjectNode.class);
        ProductList productListInstance = new ProductList();
        List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            if(node.get("hits").get("hits").isArray()){
                for (final JsonNode objNode : node.get("hits").get("hits")) {
                    Product products = new ObjectMapper().readValue(objNode.get("_source").toString(), Product.class);
                    productList.add(products);
                }
                productListInstance.setProductList(productList);
            }
            responses = productListInstance.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            responses = productListInstance.toString();
        }
        return responses;
```

actually the first json string was like this :

```
{
    "hits": {
        "hits": [
            {
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Jam Brong",
                    "image": "https://asdf.asdf.com/asdf/image/upload/w_30,h_30,c_fill/product/fb7d3dcb505fba76262c0c6383d844ae.jpg",
                    "price": "2500",
                    "slug": "133-jam-brong",
                    "short_name": "Jam Brong"
                }
            },
            {
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Jam abcfdfjn",
                    "image": "https://asdf.sdf.com/asdf/image/upload/w_30,h_30,c_fill/product/7bbd3d081dd03c442e4cb27321a7b50c.jpg",
                    "price": "10888",
                    "slug": "87-jam-abcfdfjn",
                    "short_name": "Jam abcfdfjn"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do it manually. Use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

Comment: deserialize, then serialize as something else.

Comment: @Kartik i tried, but jackson  performance to slow.

Comment: @Bobby Then you must be doing something wrong. Millions of people and frameworks are using it without issues. Try sharing that code here.

Comment: @Kartik see my updated question

Comment: @ScaryWombat how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jackson to achieve this. First, define a bean representing your data model.

```java
public static class Source {
    private String name;
    private String image;
    private String price;
    private String slug;
    private String shortName;

    @JsonCreator
    public Source(@JsonProperty("_source") Map<String, Object> rawJson) {
      this.name = rawJson.get("name").toString();
      this.image = rawJson.get("image").toString();
      this.price = rawJson.get("price").toString();
      this.slug = rawJson.get("slug").toString();
      this.shortName = rawJson.get("short_name").toString();
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
      return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
      this.image = image;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
      return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
      this.price = price;
    }

    public String getSlug() {
      return slug;
    }

    public void setSlug(String slug) {
      this.slug = slug;
    }

    public String getShortName() {
      return shortName;
    }

    public void setShortName(String shortName) {
      this.shortName = shortName;
    }
  }
```

Observe the [@JsonCreator](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) annotation on the constructor. Then write the code for serialization and deserialization:

```java
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Source[] sources = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, Source[].class);
    String converted = mapper.writeValueAsString(sources);
    System.out.println(converted);
```

Prints:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Jam Brong",
    "image": "https://asdf.asdf.com/asdf/image/upload/w_30,h_30,c_fill/product/fb7d3dcb505fba76262c0c6383d844ae.jpg",
    "price": "2500",
    "slug": "133-jam-brong",
    "shortName": "Jam Brong"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jam abcfdfjn",
    "image": "https://asdf.asdf.com/asdf/image/upload/w_30,h_30,c_fill/product/7bbd3d081dd03c442e4cb27321a7b50c.jpg",
    "price": "10888",
    "slug": "87-jam-abcfdfjn",
    "shortName": "Jam abcfdfjn"
  }
]
```

Comment: hy, your code run well, but i just got some issue about how if some field is null? for example `"name": null, "image": "https:...."`

Comment: in the constructor, before calling `toString` chuck for `null`, for each property; for example: `rawJson.get("name") == null ? null ? rawJson.get("name").toString()`

Comment: i change your code from ` Map<String, Object>` to ` Map<String, String>`

Comment: That's probably where you're getting the issue: use `Map<String, Object>` and explicitly convert it into the data type you need. This would help esp. if you have a field that's not a string.